# How to wget/curl past a redirect to download content?

Tags: linux, bash, perl, curl, wget

I would like to use `wget`, `curl` or even use Perl to download a copy of my projects each night from [ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/login), but when I look at Network in Chrome, I see it redirects from `/login` to `/projects` in a successful login.

Because of the redirect I it flushes the Chrome network debug log, but if I do a wrong login attempt I can see what it sends. See below screenshot.

**Question**

Can anyone explain how I can figure out which string I should post in order to login?

Is the `_csrf` header string important?

I have no luck with

```
curl -s --cookie-jar cookie https://sharelatex.com/login
curl -s --cookie cookie -H 'email: my@email.com' -H 'password: mypw' https://sharelatex.com/login
```

as it just gives me a failed login screen.

[image]

Comment: "Is the _csrf header string important?" Yes. If your request does not send that, the web site assumes the request is a forgery attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-L` option in `curl`:

```
curl -s -L -H 'email: my@email.com' -H 'password: mypw' https://sharelatex.com/login
```